# VBA Code from NULL #VALUE! to Zero

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below code to retrieve some data from websites.

```
Public Function giveMeValue(ByVal link As String) As String
   Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

   With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
      .Open "POST", link, False
      .send
      htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
   End With

   With htm.getelementbyid("JS_topStoreCount")
      giveMeValue = .innerText
   End With

   htm.Close
   Set htm = Nothing
End Function
```

Sometimes the element with ID `"JS_topStoreCount"` doesn't exist and the function returns `#VALUE!`. How do I modify this function so that errors are returned as `0` and are highlighted in red?

Comment: Out of curiosity here, your code has a `Do...Loop` structure with no exit condition, how on earth are you getting a return value at all? The way it's written the code should go into an infinite loop upon being called.

Comment: Aiken sorry I posted the old code , the correct one is without the loop , I would use it but I am not sure I am able to correctly use the loop function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't see the reason for the `Do Loop` so I have removed it, I've added an `if` statement to check if the html element is `nothing` before assigning it to the return value.

```
Public Function giveMeValue(ByVal link As String) As String
Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
   .Open "GET", link, False
   .send
   htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
End With

If Not htm.getelementbyId("JS_topStoreCount") Is Nothing Then

    giveMeValue = htm.getelementbyId("JS_topStoreCount").innerText

Else

    giveMeValue = "0"

End If

htm.Close
Set htm = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Matt  THX , any change that all the return 0 value  are market in red ?ALso sometimes take a while to update result so I was wandering about a button  to refresh the data ....could be possible?

Comment: You're risking a type mismatch error here as giveMeValue is a String and you're assigning the integer value 0 to it. Also you mis-spelled giveMeValue in that same statement. @user2482756 If you want to highlight a "0" result in red you'll need to add a conditional format to the cell.

Comment: I tried  the code above but the '#Value!' return as empty cell without the "0" value
Ok Get it .....

Comment: I've just updated the answer re. @Aiken 's comments! Thank you

Comment: By refresh the data, do you mean that is returned in your excel workbook? You just need to add a new call to the initial routine you are calling.

On a side not, your http request probably should be a "GET" rather than a "POST". I will update this now.

Comment: can I use 'ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll' ?

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question, I have already written my answer and will happily submit this. :-)